# Is there a perfomance difference between insertion and geometry change to the DOM?

Tags: html, performance, dom, browser

Hey I am working on a Drag and Drop Editor and came to this question. Right now if I drag an element I insert the element and an slot underneath. The slot is basically just to visualize where the dragged element will be dropped. So everytime when I drag over the editor the nearest slot height will be increased (for example 50px, otherwise it is 0).

This slot handling is kinda annoying so I was thinking that inserting a slot temporary to the DOM and remove it directly after dropping would be easier. And both (height changing and inserting) will trigger a reflow of the DOM.

Is there a performance difference between inserting an element to the DOM and changing height of an element?

Thank you in advance :)